# Editable sections in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm making a website on WP and i want some sections are editable from the *Customize* mode. I searched on forums and all but i didn't find it.

This is a picture of the problem. I want that editable sections are on the left, to modify the sections on the right. Do you understand ?

[image]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: You are chose wrong resource for that type of the question. Go [there](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You may use the **Divi Builder plugin** for the customization ... This plugin will help you to edit the content, styles, etc. from the front end page.